# I want to strikeout the contents of a xamdatagrid in MVVM model

Tags: wpf

I want to strikeout the contents of a xamdatagrid in MVVM model.I am using TextBlock.Textdecoration="Strikethrough" but it is not working.Can anyone please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using it? In C# code behind or XAML?

In XAML, it should be:

```
<TextBlock TextDecorations="Strikethrough">Sample text</TextBlock>
```

In C#, it should be:

```
textBlock1.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
```

I am not sure why u cannot get it work.

Comment: Waht you said is working.But it is not working when I put it as a style in xamdatagrid resources..I am doing this in Xaml

  <Style   TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations"  Value="Strikethrough"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontStyle" Value="Italic"></Setter>
                </Style>